# Quickbooks Authorization error

Tags: salesforce, quickbooks, apex

i have got Access token from "https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token" using rest api in apex. when i pass the response to the authorizaiton url as shown below

```
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token_secret=xEtlEPu7ljKAeWRYM6pZwY02e8ewZcZ2txR1xpix&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=qyprdc5t2G9j8TcR8AW1123BCD3iy4M0PSBwsk84Rl8WhmCa
```

i get this error

```
Oops! An error has occurred.
Please close this window and try again. 

Error Code: no_such_database 
Message: Application not found by appToken
```

Any kind of help will be much appriciable

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you figured it out but the URL for authorization actually seems different from documentation :

https://appcenter.intuit.com/Account/DataSharing/Authorize?oauth_token=YYYY
I used this url for authorization and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Authorized URL is not correct.

It should be like -

```
https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/begin?oauth_token=qyprdsGhfVztCxWPDIXbPYjVybkwxNAvUdNNaiaTabcde
```

Here oauth_token is actually request_token (not request_secret) which you get as part of the first call OAuth1.0a flow.

ie. https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token

Please refer this sample Java code which shows all the 3 steps required to generate accessToken and accessSecret (OAuth1.0a).

https://gist.github.com/manas-mukh/b6450bb28506e1302463

Comment: Thanks for the help @manas-mukherjee i have been gone through your github code before. but i am on salesforce.
I just copied your auth URL and pasted in my browser address bar replaced the auth_token with the updated one that i just got from get_request_token call. but still shows the same please see: http://screencast.com/t/d5cZrVBT9j3, i have also tried putting all the paramers but no luck so far :'(. please help

Comment: Not sure why you are forming the URL like this - 
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token_secret=<changed>&oauth_callback_confirmed=true&oauth_token=<changed>

It should be only - https://appcenter.intuit.com/connect/begin?oauth_token=qyprdsGhfVztCxWPDIXbPYjVybkwxNAvUdNNaiaTabcde

Plz correct that and try again.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try this as well - https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA

Comment: i did it from alternative way but still doesn work http://i.imgur.com/Y4b5Cnv.png :'(
none works

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with your consumerKey/consumerSecret. Please create a new one from here - https://developer.intuit.com/Application/Create/IA
If you want to connect it with sandbox then use dev consumerKey/consumerSecret otherwise same of prod. Please pass a bigger number as in the 'Access token duration' field

Comment: Not sure if you had ever tried to create a new app to try this call. Most probably, you are using tokens of a CAD app not QBO app.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of old user authorization link (https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin ) use the new link (https://appcenter.intuit.com/Account/DataSharing/Authorize)

After generating the request token and secret , redirect to the new link. This will lead to the user authorization pages. Once authorized it will redirect back to our callback url.

Code Example :

```
$userAuthUrl = "https://appcenter.intuit.com/Account/DataSharing/Authorize";

$signedUrl = "{$userAuthUrl}?oauth_callback={$callBackUrl}&oauth_consumer_key={$consumerKey}&oauth_nonce={$nonce_random}&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp={$timestamp}&oauth_token={$reqToken}&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature={$signature}";

header("Location:$signedUrl");
```